# Use of comma and periods in lists

Tags: lists

I have a doubt about how to write a list. Each item of the list must end with a comma or a period?

Comma:

1. Item 1,
2. Item 2, and
3. Item 3.

Periods:

1. Item 1.
2. Item 2.
3. Item 3.

Comment: The commas interfere. The dots are called periods and apply to sentences, but not Apples Bananas Cherries.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U...this is probably a style issue, so users will respond depending on the style guide they prefer.

Comment: @YosefBaskin , I could use semicolon instead of commas for a complex list: 1. The first item, which...; \\ 2. The second item, that....;

Comment: I depends what the list is. It might be important to make clear whether some or all are stipulations or alternatives, for example.

Comment: Bullets and paragraphing substitute for punctuation. Don't use periods or commas or semicolons in bulleted or numbered lists -- unless they consist of full sentences.

Comment: They should end in periods if they are long sentences. If brief, then no punctuation is needed at the end, since it's usually obvious. Remember that items in numbered lists are deliberately sequential while bulleted lists are not; the latter could be in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what punctuation you use is a matter that is determined by the nature of the items you are listing.

If you merely need to set out the various points in an enumeration of items such as what to do in case of a fire, you might use commas, but again you don't have to and you might revert instead to no punctuatiuon.

- In case of fire you should follow the usual directives, that is,

1. trigger off the nearest fire-alarm if there is one,
2. if there is no fire alarm nearby go to the nearest one and trigger it, and
3. get the nearest fire extinguisher and use it the best you can to put out the fire.

- In case of fire you should follow the usual directives, that is,

1. Trigger off the nearest fire-alarm if there is one.
2. If there is no fire alarm nearby go to the nearest one and trigger it.
3. Get the nearest fire extinguisher and use it the best you can to put out the fire.

If you are listing objects or concepts you might most often do away with punctuation.

- In order to be able to get through these constructions you have to use

a) a pair of scissors and a cutter
b) a ballpen or a pencil
c) a lot of cardboard (shoeboxes, …)
d) some strong glue

See for instance "[How to Punctuate Bulleted and Numbered Lists](https://intelligentediting.com/blog/how-to-punctuate-bulleted-and-numbered-lists/)"